# Verifying ARM WFI

Tags: arm

All,
  In my code I want to enter WFI on ARM V8. I am running application on Linux. I call wfi() and wait for the interrupt. Is there any way to check whether the processor core had actually entered WFI mode?

regards,
Ravi

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to execute the WFI instruction from a user mode process running under Linux? I just have to ask, "Why?" And what do you expect to happen?

Comment: put a print statement after it or in a loop with a counter, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you're running privileged code- kernel space code- you could probably toggle a GPIO (preferably with FGPIO) with a single assembly instruction before AND after the `wfi` instruction.

If you're not running in kernel space, you'd want to use UIO to do the same thing but it would be quite a hassle.

Comment: I am trying to get this information in Kernel space only. Want to get system level information on how frequently the core is getting woken up and which interrupts are causing it.

Comment: Well, set a GPIO before it sleeps- low, and then set high when it wakes. Use a trigger on an oscilloscope to see how long it's asleep/awake. Mind your bandwidth.

OR, if you can't do that, then: before it goes to sleep, capture the value of the RTC, and then when it wakes up, dump out the value of the RTC. I don't know the device, but RTCs usually do milliseconds, but maybe seconds with an arbitrary sub-second counter.

You'll have to check individual status flags (there are global NVIC registers for ARM) to check which interrupts are flagged. If this helps, I can add this to the answer.